# in the context of SVD, does the direction of basis vectors matter? I guess it does not matter, but why?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd

[image]

the figure (fig_1) shown above is generate by this [link](https://github.com/MachineIntellect/Statistical_Machine_Learning/blob/master/plot_svd.ipynb) that is trying to provide a reproduction (partly) to following wiki figure (fig_2) about [svd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition)

[image]

the direction of a basis vector (the black short one in fig_1) is opposite to the one ($\sigma_2$) in fig_2, does that matter for getting the new space (the right one in both fig_1 and fig_2)? I guess not, but why?

Comment: Please clarify your question. It matters for what? If you change the directions you get a different matrix. So what do you mean?

Comment: You can rotate singular vectors 180 degrees and get the same one. So it only encodes "orientation" and not "direction".

Comment: So is that your question, whether $\pm$ direction matters? That depends on how you define singular values; usually they are defined to be positive, so the direction *does* matter.